# How to enable OpenMP w/ OpenCV app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, openmp

i have an Open CV app that i have written that grabs a frames from a camera and processes them  in a loop.  The very first thing i do is i print out the build information for opencv.  as you can seee below OpenMP is disabled.
I did compile OpenCV and included the WITH_OPENMP option.  I am using VS 2010 professional and have specified the /openmp compiler option in properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Language.  What else do i need to do?

```
 Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use OpenMP:                  NO
    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              YES
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
```

Comment: Are you using `\openmp`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fw509c3b.aspx

Comment: yes...i set this in properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out...when i build opencv w/ the WITH_OPENMP options enabled, i had built to a different path than the path where opencv was installed. I forgot to update my environment path to point to the new /bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

To enable OpenMP library with OPENCV, I used -D WITH_OPENMP=ON option with cmake and it worked.